# FT not converging, can't find reason...is it normal to experience?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I want to implement the fourier transform of a periodic function, e.g. exp(iwt). Here is an example of how I implemented it.

```
max_f = 100
dt = 0.002

# discretized frequency
farray = np.linspace(0, max_f, 101).astype(np.float128)

# fourier transform kernel 
ft_kernel = np.exp(-1.j * 2. * (np.pi) * farray * dt)

# storage of fourier transform until current time step, for graphing purpose
store = np.zeros([1000, 101], dtype=np.complex128)

# The actual fourier transform calculated until current time step
current = np.zeros([101], dtype=np.complex128)

for i in range(10000):
    for fre in range(101):
        current[fre] = current[fre] + (ft_kernel[fre]**i) * np.exp(np.complex(1j * 2. * np.pi * 50.0 * dt * int(i)));
    # store it every 10 step to plot the convergence graph
    if i % 10 == 0:
        store[i // 10] = current

# calculate the psd
result = np.abs(store * dt)**2
```

Code for generating video:

```
from IPython.display import HTML

total_steps = 300
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 5))
ax.set_ylim(-15, 15)
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ln, = ax.plot([], [], 'b-')
ax.set_xlabel('frequency')
ax.set_ylabel('db')
title = ax.text(0.5,0.85, "", bbox={'facecolor':'w', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':5},
                transform=ax.transAxes, ha="center")
plt.close()
def animate_func(i):
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print(i , end ='')
    ln.set_data(np.linspace(0, 100, 101), np.log(result[i]))
    ax.set_title(f'{i * 10} of {300 * 10}')
    return ln,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate_func, frames = total_steps, interval=50, blit=False)
HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

Formula I'm using:
[image]
where the blue `f(t)` is the periodic function's value and in this case `exp(iwt)`.
However, when I plot the convergence out, it always have the behavior of first converge then diverge and repeats...
I can't find the reason, is it possible to seek some help here?
Here is the gif:
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do not provide a MWE that could reproduce that gif, and what you did provide is not named or commented well enough to show what formula you're trying to implement. It's incredibly contradictory, you say you want to implement a Fourier transform but you're summing over 10 `i` values, whatever those are; your `store` has 1000 arrays but your gif has 20000.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've update the question and hope to get some help from you if possible!

Comment: I don't know where you got that equation from, but it's not the Fourier Transform. The (continuos time) Fourier Transform involves an integral, and can't really be applied to a sampled function. In the computer's discrete world, use the Discrete Fourier Transform, which doesn't involve *f* nor Δ*t*. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform

Comment: Also, your equation doesn't show an iterative function, so I don't understand why you are looking for convergence. If you just apply that equation, it yields a number for each *f*.

Comment: For https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform, equation 1, if I view the greek letter Xi in that function as a frequency and I can then discretize the intergral into summation of value evaluated at each time step using any of the quadrature rule? That's where the formula come from I think.
Since the signal frequency is fixed, I thought this is similar to an iterative process to more accurately get the frequency from the signal with more time involved. No?

Comment: This isn't a DFT, it's just a plain way of discretize continuous FT for a time signal I think

Comment: Your signal doesn’t converge to 0 at infinity, and neither does the wavelet used by the Fourier Transform. Consequently, you really can’t compute that integral using numerical methods. You need to apply a window function. Might as well compute the DFT, it’s a lot easier. Is there any reason you don’t want to use the DFT? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Oh right, may caused because of the delta function in frequency! Hmm, I don't want to use DFT because the resolution of frequency expression are uniformly sampled. However, I just want a high accuracy around certain range of frequency. I don't know how to use DFT to do that. Thanks for your suggestion Cris!

Comment: There's no way around that. Computers only handle discrete values, so your input is always going to be sampled and have a finite window. You can sample more finely (easy in your case because you have the function, just sample with `linspace` and decreased `dt`) and sample for a longer window in time for the DFT to approach the FT. In cases where you can't just go back and sample more, the best you can do is pad zeros so at least you have finer frequency resolution, though your DFT/FT is still going to be convolved with a sinc or something because of the window.

Comment: You might be interested in [pitch estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm)